# MS Access - Display Custom Primary Key autonumber

Tags: ms-access

[image]I am new to MS Access. I am trying to display custom primary key auto numbers i.e. 251-01,251-02,251-03......etc in my form.

At the moment the custom generated autonumber is working fine in the table but when I try to display this on the form, it only shows 1,2,3.....etc.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?
 [image]

Comment: Can you show us the code how you are trying to display it?

Comment: I just added the picture.  I didn't use any code, just simple MS stuff

Comment: in my form i need to display 251-08 instead of just 8

Comment: Probably you have to change the Display-Format of the control showing the TM_Tp_JobNumber. It's hard to tell without seeing the code/properties of the control

Comment: You can't do that 251-08 is a string / text where as autonumber is well a number.

Comment: lokusking is correct. You need to set the format of the control. Setting the format in the table will not carry over to the form, unless it was done prior to the control being added to the form.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help guys....I managed to find an alternative way.....just had to delete the labels on the form and insert new label with control source pointing to custom PK.